# Why does Valgrind show no allocations for a Rust program?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, rust, valgrind

I'm learning Rust and I was playing with `Box`, so I tried checking leaks with `valgrind` but it shows that there are no allocations on the heap:

```
$ rustc -C opt-level=0 raii.rs
$ valgrind ./raii
==3850== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3850== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3850== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3850== Command: ./raii
==3850== 
5
Changed:10
==3850== 
==3850== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3850==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3850==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==3850== 
==3850== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3850== 
==3850== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3850== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

`valgrind --leak-check=full ./raii` shows exaclty the same result.

Here's the Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut _box2 = Box::new(5i32);

    println!("{}", _box2);
    *_box2 = 10i32;
    println!("Changed:{}", _box2);

    {
        let _box3 = Box::new(4i32);
    }
}
```

Some other info:

```
$ rustc -V
rustc 1.8.0 (db2939409 2016-04-11)

$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.10.1

$ uname -a
Linux 3.19.0-59-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 19 18:57:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why is that? I thought `Box` allocates the variable on the heap. Also, [this example](http://rustbyexample.com/scope/raii.html) shows almost the same code and Valgrind shows allocations there.

If I add the following code:

```
let _stack = (1u64, 2u64, 3u64);
let _heap = Box::new((4u64, 5u64, 6u64));
println!("Memory used by stack: {} bytes", std::mem::size_of_val(&_stack));
println!("Memory used by heap: {} bytes", std::mem::size_of_val(&_heap));
```

It prints exactly what I expected:

```
$ ./raii 
Memory used by stack: 24 bytes
Memory used by heap: 8 bytes
```

- In the second case, the tuple was placed on the heap and a pointer (8 bytes) was pushed to the stack.
- In the first case tuple was placed on the stack, so it takes 24 bytes.

Valgrind seems to be able to count heap allocations from other programs:

```
$ valgrind echo "test"
==4575== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4575== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4575== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4575== Command: echo test
==4575== 
test
==4575== 
==4575== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4575==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4575==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 30 frees, 3,681 bytes allocated
==4575== 
==4575== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4575== 
==4575== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4575== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Rust 1.32

As of Rust 1.32, the *default allocator* for an executable is [now the system allocator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1320-2019-01-17), so you don't need to set anything by default.

## Previous versions

Rust uses jemalloc as the allocator when you build a binary. The way that jemalloc is currently compiled [does not contain the Valgrind hooks needed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28224).

If you need the ability to track allocations with Valgrind, you can switch to the the system allocator if you are using nightly Rust.

See also:

- [Why does Valgrind not detect a memory leak in a Rust program using nightly 1.29.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51509314/155423)