# Why does Valgrind not detect a memory leak in a Rust program using nightly 1.29.0?

Tags: rust, valgrind

I'm trying to detect a memory leak in a Rust program using Valgrind following [this blog post](https://creativcoder.github.io/post/checking_memory_leaks_in_rust_ffi/). My source code is simply:

```
#![feature(alloc_system)]
extern crate alloc_system;

use std::mem;

fn allocate() {
    let bad_vec = vec![0u8; 1024*1024];
    mem::forget(bad_vec);
}

fn main() {
    allocate();
}
```

I expect the call to `mem::forget()` to generate a memory leak that Valgrind would be able to pick up on. However, when I run Valgrind, it reports that no leaks are possible:

```
[memtest]> cargo run
   Compiling memtest v0.1.0 (file:///home/icarruthers/memtest)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.28s
     Running `target/debug/memtest`
[memtest]> valgrind target/debug/memtest
==18808== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18808== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18808== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18808== Command: target/debug/memtest
==18808== 
==18808== 
==18808== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18808==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18808==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==18808== 
==18808== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18808== 
==18808== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18808== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I am upgraded to the latest nightly (1.29.0-nightly (6a1c0637c 2018-07-23)).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Rust 1.32

As of Rust 1.32, the *default allocator* for an executable is [now the system allocator](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1320-2019-01-17), so you don't need to set anything by default.

## Previous versions

You aren't using the global allocator setting correctly. This is a *nightly* feature, which means that it's prone to change at any time. Your blog post is out of date.

Check the [module docs for `std::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/alloc/index.html) to see the correct usage:

```
#![feature(alloc_system)]
extern crate alloc_system;

#[global_allocator]
static GLOBAL: alloc_system::System = alloc_system::System;

use std::mem;

fn allocate() {
    let bad_vec = vec![0u8; 1024*1024];
    mem::forget(bad_vec);
}

fn main() {
    allocate();
}
```

```
root@3fb431791293:/tmp/vg# valgrind target/debug/vg
==6326== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6326== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6326== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6326== Command: target/debug/vg
==6326==
==6326==
==6326== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6326==     in use at exit: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks
==6326==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 11 frees, 1,050,753 bytes allocated
==6326==
==6326== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6326==    definitely lost: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks
==6326==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6326==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6326==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6326==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6326== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6326==
==6326== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6326== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```