# Why Valgrind does not detect memory leak *again* in stable 1.55.0?

Tags: rust, memory-leaks, valgrind

This is similar but not the same as [Why does Valgrind not detect a memory leak in a Rust program using nightly 1.29.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509314/why-does-valgrind-not-detect-a-memory-leak-in-a-rust-program-using-nightly-1-29) since that one was solved in Rust 1.32

A simple reproducible sample:

```
# create a new project
cargo new hello && cd hello

cat <<EOT > src/main.rs                                       
fn allocate() {
    let bad_vec = vec![1u8; 1024*1024];
    std::mem::forget(bad_vec);
}

fn main() {
    allocate();
}
EOT

cargo build --release && valgrind target/release/hello
```

Then we get:

```
   Compiling hello v0.1.0 (/home/cs144/hello)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.23s
==16113== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16113== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16113== Using Valgrind-3.17.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16113== Command: target/release/hello
==16113== 
==16113== 
==16113== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16113==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16113==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 2,057 bytes allocated
==16113== 
==16113== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16113== 
==16113== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==16113== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Notice that, if we change `let bad_vec = vec![1u8; 1024*1024];`'s `1u8` to `0u8`, then we happily detect memory error as in the [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509314/why-does-valgrind-not-detect-a-memory-leak-in-a-rust-program-using-nightly-1-29).

Thus, I cannot use Valgrind to detect memory problems (since I have some unsafe code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I see... Using Godbolt, the code compiles to nothing (no memory allocations), probably because of Rust's optimizations. However, using the `0u8` code, it indeed compiles to something (`__rust_alloc_zeroed`), thus the memory leak really happens in that case.

Finally I use something like the following to forbid rust from optimizing out the leaky code.

```
    let ptr = Box::leak(Box::new(vec![42; 100]));
    println!("ptr={:?}", ptr)
```

Comment: Is this intended to be an edit to your question?  It certainly doesn't make sense as an answer.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley It is indeed the answer. Question is, why leak is not detected? Answer is, the code that deliberately causes the leak **is optimized away**, so of course not detected...

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I figure out the answer after I post the question, and I do not want to delete the question in case anyone has same problem as me. So I self-answered it.

Comment: If there is no leak to detect then "why is the leak not detected?" isn't even a valid question. Valgrind correctly identifies the leaks when they are actually present in the compiled binary (both in the case of `std::mem::forget()` and `Box::leak()`). If the code is modified so that the allocated memory is actually used (eg, adding a `println!("{:?}", bad_vec)`) then it does not get optimized away and the leak is detected.

Comment: @Herohtar I agree - but I did not recognize that *when* I asked the question.